# selecting each week of kendo calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

Hi Is there any way to get first day and last day of each week of Kendo Calendar? Like below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery as:

```
// Create calendar
var cal = $("#cal").kendoCalendar({}).data("kendoCalendar");

// Print first and last date on each row
$("tbody > tr", cal._table).each(function(idx, elem) {
    console.log($("td:first", elem).text(), $("td:last", elem).text());
})
```

What I do is get the table that represents the calendar `cal._table` and the iterate on each row of the body of the table.

Then I extract the text of the first and last cell of the row.

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/W9VFB/

Comment: Hi, is there any way to display first and last day of calendar? For example in the above calendar 25th Aug 2013 is the first day and 5th October 2013 is the last day. Can we get it?

Comment: do you mean including day, month and year or as in the OP the text in the cell?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to get day month and year of first and last day of displayed calendar

Comment: As far as possible do not ask a second question in the comments field since this prevents other from seeing your question (less chances for you of getting a reply) and make more difficult for others finding a solution to the same problem.

Comment: You should do var `first = $("tbody > tr:first > td:first > a", cal._table).data("value");` and `var last = $("tbody > tr:last > td:last > a", cal._table).data("value");`

Comment: Hi OnaBai, thanks for your reply. From the above code I can able to get first and last day. But I've changed my code slightly like below.  var cal = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");
        var first = $("tbody > tr:first > td:first > a", cal._table).data("value");
        var last = $("tbody > tr:last > td:last > a", cal._table).data("value"); In this case last day is giving null. Any idea?

Comment: Cannot see what did you change, where is the difference?

Comment: instead of creating new calendar like var cal = $("#cal").kendoCalendar({}).data("kendoCalendar"); Just I try to get the reference of existing calendar like var cal = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar"); Now I'm not able to see last date.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/yeyene/39QPT/1 this code is almost working for me. But there is a small bug in this. it is returning wrong month for every selection. In your example it is showing first day as 30th May 2013 instead of 30th June 2013. And last day as 10th July 2013 instead of 10th Aug 2013. Any idea?

Comment: Hey OnaBai, I'm sorry to ask you the same query, is there any chance to access last but one value? from the above code?  var cal = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar"); var first = $("tbody > tr:first > td:first > a", cal._table).data("value"); var last = $("tbody > tr:last > td:last-1 > a", cal._table).data("value");

Comment: @jestges, sorry for insisting but as far as possible do not ask a second question in the comments field since this prevents other from seeing your question (less chances for you of getting a reply) and make more difficult for others finding a solution to the same problem